# Look up for a given text value in a 2-dimensional range (matrix) and return the reference of the cell (row and column)

Tags: excel

Basically I am looking for a way to find a given text/number value in a matrix, and return the coordinates of the cell (row and column) so I can use to calculate "distances" between given cells in the matrix. Any ideas? I have been researching and found about INDEX/MATCH combinations, but MATCH only works with 1-dimension arrays.

Comment: sounds like some example data and expected results might be helpful

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, provided that the matrix contains no duplicate entries. (Otherwise, these formulas won't work.) Probably still could be done with duplicate entries, but the formula would be more complicated. For now I'll assume no duplicate entries. That said, here's what I found:

Formula to find row number:

```
= SUMPRODUCT(MMULT(TRANSPOSE(ROW(<matrix>)),(<matrix>=<input value>)+0))
```

Formula to find column number:

```
= SUMPRODUCT(MMULT((<matrix>=<input value>)+0,TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(<matrix>))))
```

Note: For both of these you will have to press `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Enter` after typing the formula in the formula box, otherwise the formula will give you an error.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way.  Let's assume that A2:E10 contains the table, and that G2 contains the value of interest.

To return the **native** row number:

```
H2, confirmed with CONTROL+SHIFT+ENTER

=SMALL(IF(A2:E10=G2,ROW(A2:E10)),1)
```

To return the **native** column number:

```
I2, confirmed with CONTROL+SHIFT+ENTER

=SMALL(IF(INDEX(A:E,H2,0)=G2,COLUMN(A2:E10)),1)
```

Note that if the value of interest occurs more than once, the row and column numbers for the first one (top left most) are returned.